# Iterating through a dictionary that starts at the first key value each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary that contains usernames in the key, and dates in the value. Because I cannot sort the dictionary alphabetically, I want to iterate through the dictionary keys (username) to match an item in a separate alphabetical ordered list that holds all the usernames and then print the associated value (date) in a spreadsheet. The problem I am running into is that when it is iterating through the dictionary, it doesn't start at the beginning dictionary key each time and the next item to match in the list has already been iterated through in the dictionary. Is there a specific iteration tool that will start at the beginning each time?

Code I have so far:

```
x=0
nd=0
for k, v in namedatedict.items():
    if k == usernamelist[x]:
        sh1.write(nd, col3_name, v)
        x += 1
        nd += 1
```

To give you some background on what I am doing, I am trying to find the date that matches the specific username and print it next to the associated username in a spreadsheet. There may be a completely different way to iterate through these value but this is the only way I could think of. Any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the alphabetical list always a subset of the total username+date set? Or is the username+date set a subset of the alphabetical list? Or are those two sets always the same? The answer to this question has a big impact on the best solution.

Comment: The two sets are always the same length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your answer to my comment, it seems that really the only reason you have the alphabetical list is to get sort-order. In that case, this problem becomes *much* simpler; Python supports sorting lists of tuples by one of their elements via the `sorted()` method. And dictionaries can provide a list of key-value tuples via the `items()` method. So, this just becomes:

```
for name, date in sorted(namedatedict.items(), key = lambda entry: entry[0]):
    # do whatever you need with the name and date. Names will be alphabetical.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Forgot that with the .items() it becomes a tuple that could then be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like that:

```
for k in usernamelist:
    sh1.write(nd, col3_name, namedatedict[k])
    x += 1
    nd += 1
```

This will iterate through the list of keys ("username") -- and get each value from the dictionary based on that key.

If `usernamelist` is not a proper sub-set of the keys of `namedatedict`, you should use `get` to get the value an be prepared to handle the case of non-existent key:

```
for k in usernamelist:
    value = namedatedict.get(k)
    if value is not None:
        sh1.write(nd, col3_name, value)
        x += 1
        nd += 1
```

you could handle that using exception too:

```
for k in usernamelist:
    try:
        sh1.write(nd, col3_name, namedatedict[k])
        x += 1
        nd += 1
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Finally, if you don't *need* to maintain a separate list to get keys in order, you could use `sorted` on the keys:

```
for k in sorted(namedatedict.keys())
    sh1.write(nd, col3_name, namedatedict[k])
    x += 1
    nd += 1
```

Comment: This works so long as the sorted list is always a subset of the dictionary's keys. Need OP to clarify that.